# AWSCognitoIdentityService.m FABKitProtocol.h file not found using Cocoapods and Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, aws-sdk

I'm not sure if this is an XCode bug, CocoaPods bug, AWS iOS SDK bug or user bug

I'm using `CocoaPods 1.0.0.beta.6`, and `XCode 7.3`

In the Podfile I have included

```
target 'ios-consumer-app' do
    pod 'AWSCore'
    pod 'AWSCognito'
    pod 'AWSKinesis'
    pod 'AWSS3'
    pod 'AWSMobileAnalytics'
    pod 'AWSAPIGateway'
    pod 'Alamofire'
...

//Podfile.lock for versions
  - AWSCognito (2.3.6):
    - AWSCore (= 2.3.6)
  - AWSCore (2.3.6)
```

but when I try to build I get the following error[image: FABKitProtocol.h file not found]

But the file exists in the `Pods/AWSCore/` group
[image: FABKitProtocol.h file exists]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was using the beta version of cocoapods. After reverting cocoapods to `0.39.0` I had no problems installing AWS `2.3.6`

Answer (score 2):

see https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/351

I've fixed back to '2.3.4'.

```
  pod 'AWSCore', '2.3.4'
  pod 'AWSCognito', '2.3.4'
```

Comment: Lol that's me asking the same question on github